# DataFrame should not overwrite the excel and append just below last data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel

While exporting the df the code is rewriting the data and rmove the existing. I want data should paste just below the last data and within the same column name.

```
file_path = "C:/Users/Home/Desktop/New/"
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.insert(loc = 0,column = 'Name',value = fullname) # after every exceuting code i have all value in fullname,addr,f_name
df.insert(loc = 1,column = 'Adr',value = addr)
df.insert(loc = 2,column = 'F_Name',value = f_name)
dfe = pd.DataFrame(df)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path + "List.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
dfe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'PG', index=False)
```

Data should extract into same columns

Comment: You need to load the original data into the dataframe and then `union`  it to the new data and write that out

Comment: Its is not working as expected

Comment: You keep writing "not working", which means nothing. Please be specific about what is not working. Getting an error? Data being overwritten?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid totally agree with u

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Using parameter `mode='a'` to append df to Excel workook in a new sheet.

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path + "List.xlsx", engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:  
    dfe.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Please ref to

> https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

---

Option 2:

To add new data to the end of an existing sheet, you can use code like the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
def main():
    file_path = r"D:/TEMP"
    # create dummy data 
    technologies =  ['Spark','Pandas','Java','Python', 'PHP']
    fee = [25000,20000,15000,15000,18000]
    duration = ['50 Days','35 Days','35 Days','30 Days', '30 Days']
    discount = [2000,1000,800,500,800]
    columns=['Courses','Fee','Duration','Discount']
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(technologies,fee,duration,discount)), columns=columns)
    print(df)
    # load data from excel
    df_org = pd.read_excel(file_path + r"/List.xlsx", sheet_name="PG")
    df = pd.concat([df_org, df], ignore_index=True)
    df.to_excel(file_path + r"/List.xlsx", sheet_name="PG", index=False) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: sorry to say but it has not worked for me

Comment: @ninja_haze_developer2484 Please try Option 2. I hope it is what you are looking for.